# jQuery autocomplete in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to set up Autocomplete on a wordpress site using PHP script.  But nothing is showing up currently in my code. I understand that general idea is to have a jQuery function that would use PHP script that would pull up MySQL data(suggest.php) in this case. Also if I were to put

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'suggest.php',
        minLength:1

    });
  } );
</script>
```

in myScript.js under js folder, how would I access it? My full code below...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'suggest.php',
        minLength:1

    });
  } );
</script>

<form action="" method="post">   
Name:   <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : '' ?>"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't include the whole `jquery-ui`, it's totally unnecessary.

Second of all, don't place your scripts manually. That's why WordPress has [enqueuing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

First you need to enqueue your script where the autocomplete will be, and it must depend on autocomplete. So in your `functions.php` you'd put

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_theme_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_theme_setup' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_theme_setup() {

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' );

    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_frontend_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'yourtheme_custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

        wp_localize_script( 'yourtheme_custom', 'yourtheme_autocomplete', array(
            'autocomplete' => json_encode($results_array), // Results array contains all your autocomplete words
        ) );
    }
}
```

How you call your `.js` file is up to you. I call it `custom.js` and put it inside /js folder in the theme.

You'll also need a `$results_array`, with all your autocomplete words here. I usually put them manually, or query the database if needed.

Then in your `custom.js` you'll put something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var autocomplete_terms = JSON.parse( yourtheme_autocomplete.autocomplete );


    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: autocomplete_terms,
        minLength: 1
    });

});
```

Should be working fine. A cool addition is if you have accents or latin extended terms is to add them to accent map

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var autocomplete_terms = JSON.parse( yourtheme_autocomplete.autocomplete );

    var accentMap = {
        "ä": "a",
        "ö": "o",
        "å": "a",
        "č": "c"
    };

    var normalize = function( term ) {
        var ret = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
            ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( autocomplete_terms, function( value ) {
                value = value.label || value.value || value;
                return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
            }) );
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So according to this solution, we would set up the functions that would utilize $results_array from MySQL query file for suggest.php in functions.php and set up custom.js? 

How would I enque custom.js in the php page?  What would be the argument for 

"wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )"

in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what the contents of your `suggest.php` file are, but the `$results_array` needs to be an array. Whether you'll write that array by hand, or create query that will return results in form of an array is not important. It is important to have an array to pass to your JavaScript file. The enqueue part is given in my code. Paste it in your `functions.php` and you'll have `custom.js` enqueued (make sure that it is located as noted). I forgot to replace `TEMPPATH` constant with `get_template_directory_uri()` function. I'll fix it now

Comment: So basically I think got the basic idea and set up the autocomplete. But I am having 2 issues. One I was not able to get the source from `suggest.php` where `json-encoded` list would be `echo`'d. If I were to input the array manually, autocomplete list does not show up on the first take, but if I click on submit botton, then it shows up. Basically my custom.js file looks like this

Comment: Update your question with all the details, this will help us find the issue quicker.

Comment: `(function( $ ) {
 $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C"
      ]; 
      
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags,
   minLength: 1
  }); 
  
 });

})( jQuery );`

I would like to change `availableTags` to `suggest.php`

Comment: You have wrapped everything in an IIFE statement, and that will execute even before the DOM is ready. Instead of `(function($))(jQuery)` wrapper, try using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`

Comment: It looks like autocomplete list is still not showing until I have searched for item once. It does show up after that. I would like to have the source `json-encode` list from `suggest.php` Would I have to do this through `wp_localize_script`?

Comment: I managed to get it work by using direct array instead of php file. Thanks! You've been very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help, I thought I was clear about array, I should have written it in the code explicitly...